# Can I Make the `seleniumAddress` field in protractor.config.js take parameters?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a Windows box and an Ubuntu box which I run my automated tests on. Currently, in my `protractor.config.js` file I have two `seleniumAddress` fields under my `multiCapabilities: [{}]` section and just comment out one or the other depending on which environment I would like to run in.

Is there a way to parameterize the `seleniumAddress:` so I can tell from my command line which environment to run in?

Something like this: `gulp e2e --suite <suiteName> --baseUrl <URL> 
--environment Windows`

Here is my current `multiCapabilities` section from my protractor conf file:

```js
    multiCapabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome',
        // seleniumAddress: "URL to webdriver-manager Windows Box",
        seleniumAddress: "URL to webdriver-manager Ubuntu Box",
        platform: 'ANY',
        version: 'ANY',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser', '--lang=en', '--window-size=1680,1050'],
            prefs: {
                'credentials_enable_service': false,
                'profile': {
                    'password_manager_enabled': false
                },
                download: {
                    prompt_for_download: false,
                    directory_upgrade: true,
                    default_directory: 'C:\\downloads\\'
                },
            },
        }
        // shardTestFiles: true,
        // maxInstances: 2
    }],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor is run on Node.js, so you should be able to pass an argument (a little more complicated), or easier, set an environmental variable:

Protractor conf snippet from the [Protractor website](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api-overview#example-spec-file) with environmental variable logic added:

```
// Use the Windows selenium if the environmental variable IS_WINDOWS is set. 
const seleniumServer = process.env.IS_WINDOWS ?
    'https://path/to/windows-silenium' : 'https://path-to-default-selenium';

exports.config = {
  // The address of a running selenium server.
  seleniumAddress: seleniumServer,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Spec patterns are relative to the configuration file location passed
  // to protractor (in this example conf.js).
  // They may include glob patterns.
  specs: ['example-spec.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
  }
};
```

I'm not quite sure what you would want to choose from (and I don't use gulp), but for the snippet above, you would probably use:

```
IS_WINDOWS=true gulp e2e --suite <suiteName> --baseUrl <URL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give this a shot here shortly.